# Flyway: MariaDB connection error with gradle but not with spring

Tags: spring, gradle, mariadb, flyway

I'm trying to execute a migration script with flyway.

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.2.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.4'
    id "org.flywaydb.flyway" version "10.0.0"
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'

java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.mariadb.jdbc:mariadb-java-client'
    implementation 'org.flywaydb:flyway-mysql'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

flyway {
    url = 'jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/something'
    user = 'root'
    driver = 'org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver'
}
```

```
# MySQL Configuration
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/something
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

When I run: `gradlew flywayMigrate`, I recieve following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':flywayMigrate'.
> Error occurred while executing flywayMigrate
  No database found to handle jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3307/something
```

When starting SpringBoot application the migration script is executed flawlessly.
So the problem cannot be the driver or connection.

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Looks correct, but the Flyaway document says that the migration should run after all classes have been compiled, maybe we should try adding a dependency on the compilation task?

Comment: Try to add 'org.flywaydb:flyway-core:10.7.2'